Is there a way to use p4 triggers to ask for a submit password
I am trying to implement a soft lock system, where we will have a password we send people before submitting.
This kind of works if people pass the password on the submit, but then everyone sees the password.
What for now is ok, as this is more a reminder.
But what if I wanted to ask the client for the password, and allow them to write it on a prompt in p4 view?
I tried setting this change=submit trigger
This works, but I want a prompt on P4V (the perforce visual client)
#!/bin/bash

# The correct password
CORRECT_PASSWORD="TrustMe"

# Extract the changelist number from the arguments
CHANGE_LIST=$1

# Get the description of the changelist
DESCRIPTION=$(p4 describe -s "$CHANGE_LIST" | awk 'BEGIN {found=0} /^\t/ {found=1} {if (found) print}' | tr -d '\t')

# Extract the password from the description
PASSWORD=$(echo "$DESCRIPTION" | grep -o "\[pass=[^]]*\]" | sed 's/\[pass=\(.*\)\]/\1/')

# Check if the extracted password matches the correct password
if [ "$PASSWORD" != "$CORRECT_PASSWORD" ]; then
    echo "Password incorrect. Submit aborted."
    exit 1
fi

exit 0


To extend P4V you'll want to look at P4VJS.  Some sites have been able to use P4VJS to define entirely custom changelist submit dialogs; that dialog could include an extra password, and you could encrypt the password to keep anyone else from being able to reuse it.
However -- what you're implementing sounds a lot like a change review process, and you might want to consider using an existing solution, like Swarm, rather than implementing your own from scratch and trying to integrate it with P4V.

I need to try P4VJS
Swarm might work, but I want a reminder to people more than a blocking.
At least at the moment.
We are a small team, and I want a reminder more than anything else.

If you just want a reminder, maybe a server-side trigger (form-out or change-submit depending when exactly you want it) that sticks a reminder in the change description and/or outputs the reminder to stdout?

Even with a prompt in P4V you're ultimately submitting a changelist to the server and you'd need to somehow encode the password there. You could possibly hash the changelist# with the password, have users put that in their change description and then check for that in your script...
Really, a better way to approach this is have a database (which could literally be a text file) that the server can access containing "allowed" changelists or users, then check the change against that.

However since you're using this as a manual way to only let certain people submit changes - just use groups. Lock out everyone from your project but then only let people in the project-submitters group submit changes. Add people temporarily to the group to let them submit, then remove them.
You can designate certain users as Owners of the group, so they can add and remove people: this way you can grant trusted engineers permission to unlock people without giving them full super access to the triggers and admin features.
Have used this method to great success during challenging releases on a few projects.

I guess this would work if I needed a really strong submit control.
But part of what I am trying to do is add a reminder to the team more than anyhting.
So the idea here is, "Are you sure you want to submit"
More than anything else.
We are a small team and I don't want super strict rules.
I also want people to get reminded every submit, even if they are on the list, and I don't want to being adding and removing people to the submit.

If it's just advisory then I agree with the suggestions from @Samwise on this question: you can customize the forms that P4 generates for changelists and include reminder text in there. You could then verify that that text has been removed.
